# Why does the iterator index in Table not work here?

Tags: syntax, iterators

I type the following command line

```
Table[D[#1,varx[[i]]] &,{i,3}]
```

where `varx` is a vector of dummy variables

```
varx = {x1, x2, x3}
```

According to this link [NonCommutativeMultiply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html), I want to obtain a vector like this

> $\left\{\frac{\partial }{\partial \text{x1}},\frac{\partial}{\partial \text{x2}},\frac{\partial}{\partial \text{x3}}\right\}$

But I got this

> [image]

It seems like the index `i` in the command `Table` does not work. I don't know why this happens. I try not to use the placeholder '#1' like this

```
Table[D[2 x1^2 + 4 x2^3 + x3^4, varb[[i]]], {i, n}]
```

And this works all fine

```
{4 x1, 12 x2^2, 4 x3^3}
```

If I want to keep the placeholder, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `With`:

```
Table[With[{v = varx[[i]]}, D[#1, v] &], {i, 3}]`
(* {D[#1, x1] & , D[#1, x2] & , D[#1, x3] & } *)
```

See the section ["Scope"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/With.html#27653) of the documentation page for `With`.   Note that `Function` (`&`) has the attribute `HoldAll`, so that the value of `varx[[i]]` needs to be inserted into the function.

The above gives a list of operators.  An alternate interpretation of what is sought is a single operator that evaluates to a list.  Here's a way:

```
grad = Block[{D}, Evaluate[Table[D[#1, varx[[i]]], {i, 3}]] &]
(* {D[#1, x1], D[#1, x2], D[#1, x3]} & *)
```

Here's another method for this particular example, based on behavior of [`D[f, {{x1, x2, ...}}]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/D.html):

```
grad = With[{v = varx}, D[#, {v}] &]
```

Both yield

```
grad[x1 + x2^2 x3]
(* {1, 2 x2 x3, x2^2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Slot` (`#`) but the pure function (`&`) should be at a different position, i.e.

```
varx = {x1, x2, x3};

Table[List[#1, varx[[i]]], {i, 3}] & @@@ {{f, g}, {h, i}}
```

> {{{f, x1}, {f, x2}, {f, x3}}, {{h, x1}, {h, x2}, {h, x3}}}